# How to raise an error based on condition in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am writing a function **my_function** to be used as tf.data.Dataset.map argument, using tf.py_function, as recommended in [the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#applying_arbitrary_python_logic).

How can I raise a **tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError** in my_function ?

**my_function**

```
def my_function(data, param):
    _, n_freq_bins, n_time_bins, channels = tf.shape(data)
    tf.cond(
        param < n_time_bins,
        lambda: 1,
        <raise tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError>
    )
    ...
```

**In my data pipeline:**

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda data, labels: (tf.py_function(my_function, [data, 100], tf.float32), labels))
```